# Laravel 5 Fatal error: Call to undefined function database_path()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

On a new Laravel 5 install on a mac, i received the following error after setting the virtual hosts and .env files

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function database_path() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/laraveltest/config/database.php on line 51
```

The line 51 contains the following:

```
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

changing it to

```
 'database' => 'dbname',
```

results in the following error

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

the `database_path` function is part of the base laravel, so if you installed it correctly it should work.

Collective\Html is an additionnal package published by the Laravel Collective.

Make sure your composer.json require the appropriate package:

```
 "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

also, make sure you have run `composer update` with the previous line in your composer.json

This command should make sure all dependencies are installed and hopefully it'll clear your issue.